# How to make 2 columns same width size? flex box

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]
As you see in this image.
I makes this design with display flex using CSS3
All I want is that make number 5 and 10 same width, but not fixed width but makes number 10 takes its width from number 5 and vice versa.

```
.flexed{
width:100%;
}
.flexed .flex{
display:flex;
}
.flexed .flex div{
width:100%;
}
```

```
<div class="flexed">
        <div class="flex head">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>text text text text</div>
        </div>
        <div  class="flex body">
            <div>6</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>10</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-basis:0 ? ...

Comment: To which should I give flex-basis?

Comment: Not working correctly when I adding this to number 5 and 10

Comment: add it to all the element

Comment: Not working as I want. I want make number 5 and 10 as table td. td width takes it width from larger one.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved using CSS grid, no need to use flexbox since your problem is based on a 2 Dimensional layout

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container .grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px
}

.container .grid div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid head">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum obcaecati beatae, exercitationem delectus neque suscipit corporis animi aspernatur. Dolor maxime, facilis labore aut inventore esse possimus a sunt voluptatum fuga?</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this solves your query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this, But why the width of your flex items are 100%?

```css
.flexed{
    width:100%;
}
.flexed .flex{
    display:flex;
}
.flexed .flex div{
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexed">
        <div class="flex head">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>text text text sdvsdvsvsdvsdtext</div>
        </div>
        <div  class="flex body">
            <div>6</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>10</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I did not want a flex size. I want something like auto.

Comment: So I think probably I don't understand your question. this working both on Firefox and Chrome Browsers. @duhok

Comment: Did you use html tables! I'm sure your answer is yes. I want makes this part of divs 5 and 10 like td so I want 5 and 10 takes it's width from the bigger one.